# How does the distribution of a random variable define the probability space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let's say we conduct a random experiment. The possible outcomes may be too complicated to describe, so we instead take some measurement (in terms of real numbers) from it which are of interest to us. Mathematically we have defined a random variable $X$ from the sample space/measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ to $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel sigma field. We then choose an appropriate probability for each Borel set, via a distribution function. Then, how does that distribution function determine the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ in theory or proves its existence? What result is implicitly used here?

I understand the probability space on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ is well defined, and that is what practically concerns us, but in theory we also have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ which pushes forward its measure to the Borel sets. Hence given the distribution on $X$ we are pulling back to $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ via $P(X\in B)=P_X(B)$. But what theorem guarantees that such a space exists?

---

*Edit for clarification:For example, let us take weather $\Omega$ of a city as the original sample space and the recorded temperature $X$ as the random variable. Suppose the distribution of $X$ is decided upon, based on empirical data. That's fine and now we can answer questions like 'what is $P(a<X<b)$'. We may not care about the probability space on $\Omega$ since all the probabilities we wish to know relate to $X$, but how do we know for sure that there exists a probability space on $\Omega$ in the first place, and further, how do we know that a probability space on $\Omega$ exists which would push its probability to yield the distribution of $X$? Unless we know that there exists such a probability space in theory, we will not be able to talk about expectation of $X$, so the knowledge that such a space exists is crucial.*

---

*Further edit:
Note that we may not have an explicit complete mathematical model of the weather ever, but that does not bother us. We do have the ability however, of taking measurements of different types and thereby getting distributions related to temperature, pressure, wind speed, historical records etc. So practically we can answer questions related to these measurements. This is so what happens in practice I think. What I want is some mathematical theorem which assures me that there exists a model of the weather space, even though it is hard/difficult/impossible to find, which pushes its probability on to these distributions.

Comment: There is no such theorem.  There can be many different random variables, with very different sample spaces $\Omega$, all having the same CDF function. Likewise, some random variables have CDF functions that cannot possibly be supported on certain sample spaces. The sample space $\Omega = \{0,1\}$ cannot support a Gaussian $N(0,1)$ random variable (regardless of the probability measure $P$);  neither can it support a discrete random variable that is uniform over $\{0,1,2\}$).

Comment: So effectively, we forget about the underlying probability space, instead just focusing on the distribution. Right?

Comment: Yes, the CDF $F_X(x)$ gives you everything you need to know regarding the computation of probabilities concerning the single random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, you do not care what its sample space $\Omega$ is.

Comment: But we should at least know whether there exists a valid probability measure on the sample space $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ at all, given the distribution. How are we assured of this? If we are not assured of the existence, how can we proceed with defining things like expectation?

Comment: In *extreme* generality, this can be technically difficult. However, the special case of any single $d$-dimensional joint distribution can be achieved by considering the random variable to be the joint quantile function while the probability space is the Lebesgue space on $[0,1]^d$. The more interesting question is about implementing a sequence of random variables, and off the top of my head I have actually forgotten how the technical details of that work out.

Comment: My question is in the context of $X:\Omega\to \mathbb R$, this means $d=1$, right?

Comment: Right, so that gives you that case.

Comment: What's the problem with taking the underlying space to be the same space as that of the distribution and X to be the identity?

Comment: In principle, nothing, but then you have to come up with a way to conjure up specific measures. This way is easier. But in practice probabilists almost never think about this, because they almost never have to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question. If you have a random variable $X$ on a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, then $P_X(A) = P(X \in A)$ for $A \in B(\mathbb{R})$ defines a measure on $B(\mathbb{R})$. This is easy to check.

Maybe you are asking about when you have an increasing right-continuous function $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and you want to create a measure $\mu$ on $B(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mu((a, b]) = F(b) - F(a)$. This is possible using Caratheodory's theorem, which says that a measure on a semialgebra $\mathcal{S}$ extends to a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{S}$. See chapter 1 of Klenke's or Durrett's probability book for details.

Comment: This isnt the question. Let me clarify. We dont have a probability space a priory. We only have a sample space. Now we construct the space on (R,B(R)) using the CDF. Practically thats what we do using appropriate extension theorem. How are we now guaranteed that there exists an appropriate probability measure on the original measurable space corresponding to our construction? We need such a measure to define expectation.

Comment: @Shahab Once you have the measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ corresponding to $F$ that satisfies $\mu((a, b]) = F(b) - F(a)$, then you have the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$. The measurable function $f$ with $\mu$ as it's distribution is the identity function $f(x) = x$ since $\mu(f \in A) = \mu(A)$. So really the task of producing measures and the task of finding a measurable function with a given distribution are the same thing.

Comment: This is close to what I am asking but not close enough. You are not distinguishing between the space for the random experiment and that of the measurement/observation. In practice we may wish to take several types of measurements from the same experiment & so this indistinguishability may cause hindrance. (actually a priory we don't have a clear idea of the sample space of the experiment but only a somewhat vague notion that one exists. (My previous comment was a little misleading). Only after we take a measurement, ie bring an RV into the picture, do we have a well defined set of measurements

Comment: @Shahab Yeah what I'm saying is that there is no distinction. In your notation, I am taking $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P) = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$ to be the sample space, where $\mu$ is a probability measure you have produced. Now $X(\omega) = \omega$ has $P(X \in A) = \mu(A)$. This is all you need in order to have access to the measure theoretic framework (expectations, fatou lemma, etc).

Comment: Ok...but that is one possibility of $(\Omega,\mathcal A, P)$. User d.k.o. & user Ian have proposed different possibilities. When we say expectation of X is k then which of these possibilities are we considering?

Comment: @Shahab Let $(\Omega_1, \mathcal{F}_1, P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_2, P_2)$ be measure spaces. If random variables $X : \Omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y : \Omega_2 \to \mathbb{R}$ have the same distribution, i.e., $P_X = P_Y$, then $E(X) = E(Y)$. This is because $E(X) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,dP_X(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}y\,dP_Y(y)$. In other words, the expectation of $X$ only depends on $X$ through $P_X$.

Comment: Thanks. One last doubt. Isn't $EX= \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) d P(\omega)$? Whence from it becomes $E(X)= \int_{\mathbb R} x d P_X(x)$? Did you use some result here?

Comment: @Shahab : On your comment: "This isnt the question. Let me clarify. We dont have a probability space a priory. We only have a sample space. Now we construct the space on (R,B(R)) using the CDF." Where do you get the CDF from?  Now if you assume you have a sample space $\Omega$ and a given CDF, then my very first comment to you shows that sometimes the CDF cannot be supported by that $\Omega$. You cannot take any sample space and any CDF and assume they are compatible.  It is not clear why you ignore that answer and continue asking the question.

Comment: @Michael I understood what you said, and as of now I have only 1 doubt left regarding user Mason's remark about E(X).

Comment: @Shahab : In that case, perhaps you can answer my question "Where do you get the CDF from?"  Specifically, are you assuming you are arbitrarily given a nonempty set $\Omega$ and a function $F_X(x)$ that is nondecreasing, right continuous, and has limits $1$ and $0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ and $x\rightarrow -\infty$?  Or is there some additional assumption about how $\Omega$ and $F_X(x)$ are related? [It sounds like you are *also* assuming a probability measure exists, and then asking how to prove a probability measure exists under the assumption that a probability measure exists.]

Comment: @Michael perhaps an example: I measure temperature everyday of my city and collect lots of data. I hypothesize that temp is normally distributed with some parameters and am also further reassured of this by testing goodness of fit. This is how I get the CDF in practice from. I neither know the weather model in detail, nor I care about it, because I need tangible answers related to temp which I can answer from the distribution(contd)

Comment: All I was bothered about a math model which would incorporate this, where temp is a measurable function from some  $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ to $(\mathbb R,B(\mathbb R))$- existence of such a model would justify using all the mathematical results. Users d.k.o., Ian & Mason have proposed different models and I am satisfied with that now

Comment: Your example seems to contradict your earlier claim that you are given a sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134761/discussion-between-shahab-and-michael).

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in the example, a "probability space" is a model of an experiment. In some cases it is easy to create such a model. In the rolling a dice example, one can specify explicitly $\Omega$, $\mathcal{A}$, and $\mathsf{P}$. In your example, it is not clear at all what $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ is. So one can "model" it by specifying the joint distribution of all the observables. Suppose that you measure temperature $X$ and pressure $Y$ and specify their joint cdf $F$. Then   you set $\Omega=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, and $\mathsf{P}$ such that
$$
\mathsf{P}((\infty,a]\times (\infty,b])=F(a,b).
$$
Put $X(\omega)=\omega_1$ and $Y(\omega)=\omega_2$. Then $X$ and $Y$ has the correct joint distribution:
$$
\mathsf{P}(X\le x,Y\le y)=\mathsf{P}(\{\omega:\omega_1\le x,\omega_2\le y\})=F(x,y).
$$

Comment: That isnt the question. I wrote 'modelled in some way' in my post which was misleading to the spiriit of the question. In actual practice, $\Omega$ is rarely having a complete model, and we rarely care about it having a complete model as all our questions are answered by the distribution of X.

Comment: The weather may depend on millions of factors, temperature being one of them. The actual model would have to incorporate all of these factors. My qiestion is  all I need is the assurance that such a model exists with a probabibility measure that when pushed forward yields the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Perhaps the question is ill posed, or makes more sense from a statistical perspective then a mathematical one.

Comment: @Shahab That's what I did. Given any joint distribution (of measurements, $X$), one can always construct a probability space and random variables corresponding to those measurements such that $\mathsf{P}\circ X^{-1}$ gives that joint distribution.

Comment: You can even define a stochastic process given a family of finite dimensional distributions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem.

Comment: Yes, but thats not the question. In actual practice the joint distribution isn't available explicitly, yet we get the distribution of X from empirical data and proceed. Please see the updated post

Comment: @Shahab Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_theory. "The probabilistic approach assumes that the measured data is random with probability distribution dependent on the parameters of interest".

Comment: That is, one assumes that observables are random quantities with some joint distribution. Your goal, as a statistician, is to recover that distribution (or its parameters) from the observed data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134745/discussion-between-shahab-and-d-k-o).

Answer (score 0):

I recieved three answers, two of them in comments; and so I am posting this answer which contains a summary. It maybe of some help to future readers:

We deduce the distribution $F$ of some 'measurement' in practice. To give a mathematical framework to this measurement in the context of RVs as understood in measure theory, we need to define the entire setting.

1. User's Mason and d.k.o. have proposed letting $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$ (user Mason talked about the case n=1, and d.k.o. about the case $n=2$) where $n$ is the number of random variables (or measurements in my parlance), together with the Borel sigma field and the given distribution(s) inducing the probability measure. Each RV $X$ is defined as the projection map.
2. User Ian has proposed letting $(\Omega=(0,1),\mathcal B(0,1),\lambda)$ and defining $X(\omega)=\inf\{x\in\mathbb R:F(x)\le \omega\}$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. If more than one measurement is taken, then we may work with $(0,1)^n$ (similar to above).